# CSS - Div get remainder width space of parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, width

I'm trying to make a responsive content like this [image]
The picture stays on that width in smaller screen, and I want the texts to occupy the remainder space to make it 100% of parent.

So far I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="comment">
   <div class="image"><img>Image here</img></div>
   <div class="text">Contents</div>
</div>

.comment {
   width: 100%;
}
.image {
   width: 50px;
   float: left;
}
.text {
   float: left;
}
```

I'm open to jQuery solution, but prefers CSS only. Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float` and add `overflow: hidden` i.e.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.comment {
  width: 100%;
}
.image {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
   <div class="image"><img src="" alt="Image here"></div>
   <div class="text">Contents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes hereContents goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! :) If you don't mind can you explain why it works with overflow?

Comment: @Rosiana accept the answer , is this working for you

Comment: @Rosiana `overflow: hidden` property sets layout of the `div` and it doesn't drop if more content is added. In short if you will `float` an element left / right and you wants next sibling to take full space, this property is for you.